# Vue router, I dont' get why these two ways of specifying the routes yeild a differnet screen layout

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple vue app, in the code are 2 different ways to declare routes, which should be identical, but which yield very different screen results.

The top block, yields the correct answer with the header and the routes displayed.

The bottom does not

```
// Vue imports
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

// 3rd party imports
import Auth from '@okta/okta-vue'

// our own imports
import Hello from '@/components/Hello'
import FoodRecords from '@/components/FoodRecords'

// using Eric's free developer acct
//Vue.use(Auth,
//  {
//    issuer: 'https://dev-988388.okta.com/oauth2/default',
//    client_id: '0oao1o5c8dQikT7lC4x6',
//    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/implicit/callback',
//    scope: 'openid profile email'
//  });


// using JCDCs account (Tennant)
Vue.use(Auth,
  {
    issuer: 'https://webauth.jobcorps.org/oauth2/default',
    client_id: '0oa512tkwwgEyw3oD357',
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/implicit/callback',
    scope: 'openid profile email'
  });




Vue.use(Router);

/*// ----------------------------shows the header
let router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Hello',
      component: Hello
    },
    {
      path: '/implicit/callback',
      component: Auth.handleCallback()
    },
    //{
    //path: '/implicit/callback',
    //component: Auth.handleCallback()
    //},
    {
      path: '/food-records',
      name: 'FoodRecords',
      component: FoodRecords,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
  ]
});
//*/
//*  //----------------------doesn't show the header
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Hello',
    component: Hello
  },
  {
    path: '/implicit/callback',
    component: Auth.handleCallback()
  },
  {
    path: '/food-records',
    name: 'FoodRecords',
    component: FoodRecords,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    }
  },
];



let router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',//okta specific - EWB
  routes
});
//*/

router.beforeEach(Vue.prototype.$auth.authRedirectGuard());

export default router
```

Top layout
[image: with header]
Bottom view

[image: without header]

Here is the app.vue that specs the header

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <header>
      <b-navbar toggleable="md" type="light" variant="light">
        <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
        <b-navbar-brand to="/">Food Tracker</b-navbar-brand>
        <b-collapse is-nav id="nav-collapse">
          <b-navbar-nav>
            <b-nav-item to="/food-records">Food Records</b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item href="#" @click.prevent="login" v-if="!user">Login</b-nav-item>
            <b-nav-item href="#" @click.prevent="logout" v-else>Logout</b-nav-item>
          </b-navbar-nav>
        </b-collapse>
      </b-navbar>
    </header>
    <main>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    data () {
      return {
        user: null
      }
    },
    async created() {
    await this.refreshUser()
  },
  watch: {
    '$route': 'onRouteChange'
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      this.$auth.loginRedirect()
    },
    async onRouteChange() {
      // every time a route is changed refresh the user details
      await this.refreshUser()
    },
    async refreshUser() {
      // get new user details and store it to user object
      this.user = await this.$auth.getUser()
    },
    async logout() {
      await this.$auth.logout()
      await this.refreshUser()
      this.$router.push('/')
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

main {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

header {
  margin: 0;
  height: 56px;
  padding: 0 16px 0 24px;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  color: #ffffff;
}

header span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  letter-spacing: .02em;
  font-weight: 400;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 16px;
}
</style>
```